# usb 3.0 hub only seen as 2.0

Tags: usb

I have a usb 3.0 powered hub connected to a usb 3.0 portion my pc

It works for mass storage like usb drives and sticks...

I can't use my Blu-ray drive in usb 3.0 enclosure and I can't play dvds

My steam controller isnt recognised via the hub but it is when I plug it into the pc directly.

How can I diagnose what's wrong and make it work correctly?

Ubuntu 18.04
Gigabyte FX990 UD3
FX8350
32gb ram

Comment: It probably has nothing to do with what you have in the question's title. External optical drives usually don't work with hubs due to insufficient (or badly managed) power supply.

Comment: If you connect the DVD directly to the computer, rather than the hub, does it work?  It may help a little to know the brand/model of the USB hub